# Crossword Day puzzle

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> This article is a stub. You can help StackExchange by expanding it.

Crossword Day is coming! (Maybe a better name for this regional holiday is "cryptic crossword day".)
Here is a themed crossword. Nine of the clues contain an extra word each.
Can you figure out the theme?

---

**Crossword Grid** (Not confirmed yet)
enter image description here

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # . # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # . # . # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # . # . . . . . # # # # #
# # # # # # # # . # . # . . . . # # # # # # # # #
# # # # . # . . . . . # # . # . # # # # # # # # #
# # # # . # # # . # . . . . . . # # # # # # # # #
. . . . . # . # . # . # . # # . # # # # # # # # #
# # # # . . . . . . . # . # # # . # # . . . . . .
# # # # # # . # # # . # . . . . . # # # # . # # #
# # # # # . . . . . . # . # # # . # # # # . # # #
# # # # # # # # . # . # . # # # . . . . . . . # #
# # # # # # # # . # # . . . . . # # . # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # . # # # # # # # # # . . . . . # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # . . . . . . . # . # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . . . . . # # #
```

Sorry, the image version got deleted, so the plaintext has to be uploaded.

**Clues**

- Testing edition, mixing the asphalt *(removed - ST)*
- An exotic way of saying "Good! Very Outstanding, first place"
- 8-bit integer is located as non-intelligent
- Brown triangle appears with the dot, top of the asymptote
- God started expanding first signs of cholera
- Broadcasting company (FOX) starts to encode music
- *Game of Jumps Letters for Beginners*: Make it as short as possible
- Hostel without top over-service?
- Number origin obscured within diacritics
- A hook you lay at present, with shirt for the lady
- Some book I love: "Lazy Grand"
- Return a million secretly for dog bean
- Hardware idle
- Unfinished story *Mission begun, Element 4* (first reduplicated this month)
- Heavy metal vehicle statuette
- Illegally shoot a senior member
- Born from London district, before that French city in Canada
- Capital "O" in "Partner *O*f `10`"?
- "Quick range" is wrongly a wrongdoing inserted
- Japanese word for music
- You note the setter shape at a fixed speed
- Winner from *Victoria's Secrets*
- How his key sunk from the liquid
- A type of fish discovered by Roentgen
- "American pull" with two points
- Black donkey's home and place to defecate, I heard?

---

Task:

> Solve the crossword and find the theme.

Optional task:

> Improve the wording of the clues.

Hints are currently not available.

Comment: Sorry for the bad wording of the clues. I'm still not really good at using [indicators](http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~mark/random/indicators/).

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that I can't access Imgur images.

Answer (score 5):

The completed grid (in text form since OP cannot get at
imgur images):

> ```
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . J . . . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . U . S . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . L . I N D I A . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . T . N . M I K E . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . Z . B R A V O . . E . R . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . U . . . N . V I C T O R . . . . . . . . .
> H O T E L . L . G . E . H . . A . . . . . . . . .
> . . . . U N I F O R M . A . . . G . . Q U E B E C
> . . . . . . M . . . B . R O M E O . . . . C . . .
> . . . . . Y A N K E E . L . . . L . . . . H . . .
> . . . . . . . . I . R . I . . . F O X T R O T . .
> . . . . . . . . L . . D E L T A . . R . . . . . .
> . . . . . . . . O . . . . . . . . . A L P H A . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . W H I S K E Y . A . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . P . . . .
> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . O S C A R . . .
> ```

Order of insertion into the grid:

> november uniform yankee victor charlie kilo zulu hotel romeo juliet
>  golf foxtrot xray alpha papa whiskey lima delta sierra india mike oscar
>  tango bravo echo quebec

Theme:

> Letters of the alphabet. The 26 answers are the 26 letters
>  of the usual phonetic alphabet (though I think officially those
>  are meant to have some unorthodox spellings like ALFA and JULIETT),
>  in alphabetical order.
>  The extra words are THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER A LAZY DOG.
>  Oddly, they *mostly* appear in order in the clues, but not quite.

Brief explanations:

> ALPHA = (ASPHALT - ST)*.
>  BRAVO: I am not actually sure where the BRA comes from. VO are V(ery) O(utstanding).
>  CHARLIE = CHAR + LIE (though it seems like the clue implies LIES).
>  DELTA = DEL + T(he) A(symptote); DEL "appears with the dot" on the numeric keypad of a computer keyboard. (Thanks to MOehm, in comments, for explaining DEL; I don't think I would ever have thought of that.)
>  ECHO = E(xpanding) + CHO(lera). Strictly speaking Echo was an Oread, not a god.
>  FOXTROT = FOX + T(O) + ROT (the last as in ROT13).
>  GOLF = G(ame) O(f) L(etters) F(or).
>  HOTEL = HOSTEL without S(ervice).
>  INDIA = substring.
>  JULIET = J + U + LIE + T (the last as in tee-shirt).
>  KILO = substring.
>  LIMA = reversed substring.
>  MIKE: I confess that I don't understand this clue at all. Perhaps "hardware" is the def. Is there someone called Mike Idle? (*Eric* Idle I know of.)
>  NOVEMBER = NOVE(l) + M(ission) + BE(ryllium) + R(eduplicated).
>  OSCAR = OS + CAR.
>  PAPA = PAP (as in paparazzi) + A.
>  QUEBEC = QUE before B + EC.
>  ROMEO = ROME + O.
>  SIERRA = SI* + A with ERR inserted.
>  TANGO: I think the "wordplay" is just that "tango" is a Japanese word?  **EDIT by Scratch---Cat:** "Tango" is a Japanese word that means "word".
>  UNIFORM: U + N + I + FORM.
>  VICTOR: substring.
>  WHISKEY: substring.
>  XRAY: X + RAY. Perhaps type->X is a reference to Jaguar cars?
>  YANKEE: YANK + 2xE.
>  ZULU: homophone of "zoo loo".

Comment: (The first part of clue 4 comes from what "appears with the dot" on the numeric keypad.)

Comment: @MOehm You are obviously right. I am pretty sure I would not have thought of that in ten years.